# new language in joomla module

Tags: xml, joomla, module

i have the problem that a module from us dont have a german language but we use a german joomla. So insteat of names i only get XML Codes like "MOD_SLIDESHOWCK_OPTIONS_SLIDES" insteat of "Slidemanager".

I look into the module and i saw that in the folder language there is only en-GB avaible. So i copy-pasted the folder an rename it to "de-DE" and the file also from "en-GB.mod_slideshow" to "de-DE.mod_gu_slideshow".

i also add that files into the main xml.

```
<languages>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_slideshow.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_slideshow.sys.ini</language>
    <language tag="de-DE">language/de-DE/de-DE.mod_slideshow.ini</language>
    <language tag="de-DE">language/de-DE/de-DE.mod_slideshow.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

But in the joomla backEnd i still see the XML Codes. What must i do to see the correct words from the .ini files?

Thank you for your answers.

Thomas

Comment: You mean 'from "en-GB.mod_slideshow.*" to "de-DE.mod_slideshow.*"' instead of 'from "en-GB.mod_slideshow" to "de-DE.mod_gu_slideshow"', right?

Comment: As pointed by @nibra do check the file names. They should match with whatever you provide between language tags.